# java - printing out a date (as as string) using javafx - keeps printing current date

Tags: java, javafx, jodatime

Here is the code from my patient class and the `JavaFx` code to display it. However, each time I add a new object to the queue and refresh, the time displayed is the current time rather than each individual time...`

```
public String getTime() {
    DateTime d = new DateTime();

    String s = null;
    s = d.toString();

    return s;
}

public void setTime(String time) {
    this.time = time;
}
```

I'm using `jodatime` to convert the current `datetime` to a `string` and then display this...

```
@FXML
private TableColumn<Patient, String> timeColumn;

timeColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Patient, String>("time"));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change your getTime() to :

```
 public String getTime() {

    DateTime d = new DateTime();

    String s = null;
    s = d.toString();

    return s;
}
```

to :

```
    public String getTime() {
    return this.time;
}
```

Because your `getTime()` keeps on giving the currentTime, and not actually the time you store using `setTime()`.

Comment: thanks for the reply! Would i then need to change my setTime() method to ensure that it is always set to the current time?

Comment: No, your SetTime() function is good, but you need to be careful how you call it, don't send your setTime() currentTime, but the time you need, and do forget to use the toString and you'll be fine @fst104